# Video player that gets video source and data from json file

Tags: javascript, json, html5-video

Trying to build a video player that gets video data from a json file ie src & title. Visually it would be a player with 3 links below that load different videos into the player when clicked.

My code so far is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="hook">
<video onended="playNext()" width="640" height="480" id="myVideo"     controls autoplay>

    </video>
</div>

<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="vid1" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></a>  </li>
    <li><a id="vid2" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></a></li>
    <li><a id="vid3" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /.hook -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var conUrlCount = 0;
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

//parsedData should be declared outside the function scope since we want it     to be accessible from outside
var parsedData;
var callback = function (text) {
parsedData = JSON.parse(text);
console.log('parsed',parsedData)
conUrlCount = 0;
//after load play the first video
playNext();
};

//when page is loaded, data in json file is parsed and returned
function loadFunction() {
//returning json data
//ajax.get("clips.json", callback);

//simulate
getAjax(callback);
};


function playNext() {
if (!parsedData) {
    return
}
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
myVideo.src = parsedData[conUrlCount]['content-url'];
myVideo.play();
conUrlCount+1;
}


//to simulate
function getAjax(callback) {
setTimeout(function () {
    callback(JSON.stringify([{
        "id": "vid1",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video1.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
    }, {
        "id": "vid2",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video2.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
    }, {
        "id": "vid3",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video3.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
    },{
        "id": "vid4",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video4.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
    }  ]))
}, 100)
}

loadFunction();

document.getElementById("vid1").addEventListener("click", loadFunction);
document.getElementById("vid2").addEventListener("click", loadFunction);
document.getElementById("vid3").addEventListener("click", loadFunction);

</script>
```

At the moment I cant get the bottom 3 tiles to load into the player?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I see it. So You're firing the callback function when a video is clicked, right? You're always setting the conUrlCount to 0 every time it is clicked. Assuming that I understand your code correctly, doesn't this represent the video that you want to load?

Comment: Yes, that's right and yes, changing the value of conUrlCount to 1 or 2 lets the other video(s) play. How do i set his so that video1 plays on start and when tile 1,2,3 is clicked their respective videos load into the player?

Comment: Setting conUrlCount in that function will mean that video 0 is always played. Try sending it as a callback value to your loadFunction in your event listeners, such as `document.getElementById("vid1").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(0))` or `document.getElementById("vid2").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(1))` and in your loadFunction pass it on to the callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from our comments, something like the following should do it;

```
var callback = function (text, video) {
        parsedData = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log('parsed', parsedData)
        conUrlCount = video;
        //after load play the first video
        playNext();
};

   function loadFunction(video) {
        //returning json data
        //ajax.get("clips.json", callback);

        //simulate
        getAjax(callback, video);
    }

    //to simulate
function getAjax(callback, video) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(JSON.stringify([{
            "id": "vid1",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video1.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
        }, {
            "id": "vid2",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video2.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
        }, {
            "id": "vid3",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video3.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
        }, {
            "id": "vid4",
            "name": "#",
            "description": "#",
            "content-url": "video4.mp4",
            "thumb-url": "#"
        }]), video)
    }, 100)
}

document.getElementById("vid1").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(0));
document.getElementById("vid2").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(1);
document.getElementById("vid3").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(2));
```

Note the changed functions. I've added a video variable to your callbacks to signal the video that needs to play. You can call this at any time (including on page load) by using `loadFunction(0)` for example.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. Console says; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'content-url' of undefinedplayNext @ index.html:51callback @ index.html:34(anonymous function) @ index.html:60
index.html:31 parsed [Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that you also need to pass the variable from getAjax to callback, see my updated answer;

Comment: Thanks, the console is now sorted but only video3 plays, i guess only this one loads - document.getElementById("vid3").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(2));

Comment: And changing the last loadfunction(2) to loadfunction(0) gives me the first video again.

Comment: (0) should be the first video, (1) the second, (2) the third and so on.

Comment: Yes, thats how it should be, but atm it starts with video3 when the code is like thisdocument.getElementById("vid1").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(0));
document.getElementById("vid2").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(1));
document.getElementById("vid3").addEventListener("click", loadFunction(2));